# Sweet pickles for home canning

Tags: canning

I want to substitute some natural cane sugar for white sugar, because I don't have enough of the white to make pickle recipe. The recipe calls for 7 cups of sugar, and I have 4 1/2 of refined white sugar so I want to use the rest in natural cane sugar. Will this work?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you should be fine with a mixture of sugars as it is mostly for flavoring. The main point is to make sure the sweetener is fully dissolved in your pickling liquid.

One user asked a similar question [about using honey](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/55724/can-you-substitute-honey-for-sugar-in-a-pickling-brine), and searching the web also produced recipes for how to [use sugar substitutes](https://www.splenda.com/recipes/bread-and-butter-pickles-recipe) in place of sugar for pickling.

Comment: thank you, wasn't sure, will know for next time, I have done so many pickles this yr. probably close to 100 jars of all kinds, and my cukes keep coming faster than I can process, I ran to store and got the white, that is the only time I use refined sugar, so didn't want to mess up my recipe for lack of trip to store

Comment: I haven't been canning or pickling for too long, so treat this accordingly, but I routinely use natural sugars as a substitute for the pure-white refined stuff and have seen no adverse effects whatsoever. If anything I think it tastes better.